# Calculating attainable $\alpha$-values of non-randomized permutation tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I don't understand how to calculate the so-called *attainable $\alpha$-values* of non-randomized permutation tests. I'm reading the book "Permutation Tests for Complex Data: Theory, Applications and Software" by Fortunato Pesarin and Luigi Salmaso. They give a definition based on the survival function which I don't understand. As far as I know the survival function calculated on the observed data is a step function. A step function is a piecewise constant function, so I'd say that the derivate in any point is zero. This is the extract from the book:

[image]

where:
$X$ is the dataset
$X^*$ is a permutation of the dataset
$T$ is the test statistic
$\chi_{|X}$ is the permutation sample space
$T_0=T(X)$ is the value of $T$ calculated on observed data $X$
$T_{\alpha}$ is the critical value of the test
$\tau_{X}$ is the permutation support induced by the pair ($T$,$X$) containing all possible values assumed by T as $X^*$ varies in $\chi_{|X}$.

Suppose that the permutation distribution of T is:
[image]
How am I supposed to calculate attainable $\alpha$-values?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pmf that goes with the distribution you give is

```
  -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3  
  0.05  0.10  0.20  0.30  0.20  0.10  0.05
```

The cdf is then

```
  -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3  
  0.05  0.15  0.35  0.65  0.85  0.95  1.00
```

So (assuming we only care about $\alpha<0.5$) attainable significance levels for a one-tailed test are:

```
  0.05  0.15  0.35
```

For a two-tailed test

```
  0.10  0.30
```

Comment: Thank you. You have made a little mistake in writing the smallest $\alpha$ value for the two tailed test. So if I choose a significance level from the attainable $\alpha$ values I get an exact test, otherwise the test is conservative? Is it true that I'll never get an anticonservative test?

Comment: Thanks, yes I fixed the typo. You can certainly get an anticonservative test; for example if you wanted a test at the 5% significance level but you chose a rejection rule such that the actual type I error rate was 5.19% (e.g. a Mann-Whitney with m=5, n=6, two tailed), that's anticonservative. If, however, you insist that "we can only choose a rejection rule whose significance level is no greater than the desired significance level" then *by that insistence* you cannot get an anticonservative test.